# Link content type to funtion on Telebot Python

Tags: py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I am building a Telegram Bot using telebot with python. I ask users to updload a picture, for which I created a command "foto". When they do `/foto`, I ask them to updload a content type "photo". However, they can upload pictures regardless of the command; they just click on upload a picture and that's it. How can I link the "upoload photo" to the command, so that they can only upload a picture after writing "`/foto`"?

```
 @bot.message_handler(commands=['foto']) def send_welcome(message,
 chat_id):
     chat_id = message.chat.id
     send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Subí tu foto.')
     bot.register_next_step_handler(send, photo())
     return 
 
 @bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"]) def photo(message):
     fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
     logger.info("User_id, fileID", message.from_user.id, fileID)
     file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
     #print('file.file_path =', file_info.file_path)
     downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
     with open(f"./images/{fileID}.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
         new_file.write(downloaded_file)
     send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Foto recibida, gracias!')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cant restrict users from sending files

what you can do is to capture the files only after the command is used

for more info please read [docs](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en)

Answer (score 0):

## Code it's fix

use this :

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['foto']) 
def upload(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Subí tu foto.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, photo)

def photo(message):
    fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
    logger.info("User_id, fileID", message.from_user.id, fileID)
    file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
    #print('file.file_path =', file_info.file_path)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(f"{fileID}.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    send = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Foto recibida, gracias!')
```